# Python 3 - Randomly printing items from list of dictionaries without repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

I have a modified version of some code I am using in a quiz, my problem is my code is using random.choice to select a quiz question, how do I have it still randomly select a question but also not repeat a question already asked to the user?

Appologies for the odd questions and answers in "quiz_data"

Code:

```
def InformationToDictionaries():
quiz_data = [
    {
        "question": "What day is it today?",
        "choices": {"a": "Monday", "b": "Friday", "c": "Wednesday", "d": "Sunday"},
        "answer": "Wednesday")
    },
    {
        "question": "What food am I thinking of?",
        "choices": "Pizza", "b": "Curry", "c": "Pie", "d": "Pasta"},
        "answer": "Curry"
    }
]
return quiz_data


def Quiz():
    score = 0
    for i in range(1,6):
        q = random.choice(quiz_data)
        print("Q." + str(i) + ": ", q.get("question"))
        print('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(x, y) for x, y in q.get("choices").items()))
        userans = str(input("\n>"))

    if userans == q.get("answer"):
        print("Correct")
        score = score + 1
    else: print("Incorrect")

quiz_data = InformationToDictionaries()
Quiz()
```

Many thanks for any responses in advance, if you have any suggestions for me please let me know, this is my first question.

--------EDIT 1----------

Modified code after first suggestions:

```
def Quiz():
score = 0
random.shuffle(quiz_data)
for question in quiz_data:
    q = random.choice(quiz_data)
    print("Q." + str("1") + ": ", q.get("question"))
    print('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(x, y) for x, y in q.get("choices").items()))
```

Comment: `quiz_data` (the one at the top) is a list, not a dictionary. You can just shuffle that list and take questions in the shuffled order to insure that you won't get duplicates.

Comment: @BilltheLizard so I use random.shuffle? And then print the items in order?, my problem with that is I would still like to ask the questions in a random order.

Comment: Yes, shuffle them before the loop, then just print them inside the loop (getting rid of the call to `random.choice`).

Comment: @BilltheLizard as **Joaquim Ferrer** also mentioned I have tried this method and although finding the questions will indeed be in a random order, I still get duplicates?

Comment: Please post the code that you're using now.

Comment: @BilltheLizard done

Comment: Get rid of `q = random.choice(quiz_data)`. That's still picking a random question from the shuffled array. Just use the `question` variable in place of `q` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modified code, you're still picking a random question inside the loop. You can just take them in the shuffled order if you get rid of the line `q = random.choice(quiz_data)` and use the `question` variable in the loop body.

```
score = 0
random.shuffle(quiz_data)
for question in quiz_data:
    print("Q." + str("1") + ": ", question.get("question"))
    print('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(x, y) for x, y in question.get("choices").items()))
```

Comment: You're welcome. One other thing I see that I would change is that it always prints 'Q.1:". You can change that to a counter in place of `str("1")`.

Comment: Yeah it was just a placeholder so the code would run, I do have one other question though, would it be difficult to have the question choices also be in a random order, I appreciate the choices already are assigned to a,b,c etc in the dictionary I just was wondering if there was a simple solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @G.W If you change `choices` to a list instead of a dictionary in `quiz_data`, you could shuffle those too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Like removing the question from the list after you use it or shuffle the array and iterate through it.

To get all questions by removing them from the array each time they are picked:

```
while(len(quiz_data) != 0):
  q = random.choice(quiz_data)
  quiz_data.remove(q)
  #do stuff with q
```

If you want to iterate through a shuffled array:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(quiz_data)
for question in quiz_data:
  pass #this is only here for the code to run
  #do stuff with question
```

Both these ways are going to give you all the questions in a random order